# Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.patch

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I am trying to update the "state" of an assignment within Google Classroom using Google Apps Script. The current state of the assingment is DRAFT.

I am trying in two different codes and get two different errors:

```
function publicarBorradores() {
      var courseId = "320315007220"
      var assingid = "320315007244"
      var newState = { "state":'PUBLISHED'}

     var patchDraft = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.patch(newState,courseId,assingid);
     patchDraft.updateMask = newState;
```

or

```
      patchDraft.updateMask = 'state'
         }
```

I always get the same Error:
"*GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.courseWork.patch failed with error: updateMask: Update mask is required*"

I also tried this other way:

```
function valoresDraft (){
     var courseId = "320315007220"
     var assingId = "320315007244"
     changeState(courseId,assingId);
    }

 function changeState(courseId,assingId) {
      var estado = {'state': "PUBLISHED",}
      const patchDraft = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork
      patchDraft.patch(estado, courseId, assID,{"updateMask":"state"});
  }
```

And I get a different error: "*API call to classroom.courses.courseWork.patch failed with error: @ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.*" which is strange as I am the owner of the class AND I have published via the same "Developer Console project" other publications within this same class. (The class was NOT created via API. I created it manually from within classroom.google.com)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### The are a few issues with your code:

1. In the first example, the `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.courseWork.patch failed with error: updateMask: Update mask is required"` error you are receiving is due to the fact that you are not specifying the `updateMask` field **before** making the request.

So even though you added the `patchDraft.updateMask = newState;`  line, this won't help as it will be execute **after** the API call.

2. The second example ends up executing properly because you supplied the `updateMask` field at the time of making the request.

However, since the class was created manually from the Classroom UI, this is the expected behavior, as the class is essentially not associated with any Developer Console Project.

According to the documentation:

> `ProjectPermissionDenied` indicates that the request attempted to modify a resource associated with a different Developer Console project.
>
> *Possible Action:* Indicate that your application cannot make the desired request. It can only be made by the Developer Console project of the OAuth client ID that created the resource.

What you can do in this situation is to create the class from the API and afterwards execute the `patch` call.

#### Reference

- [Classroom API Access Errors](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors).

Comment: Thank you Ale13! Strange that you can post/publish coursework via API on classes created manually, but you cannot edit/patch coursework via API on those sames classes.